# What is the equivalent of Matlab "axis xy" in Matplotlib?

Tags: python, matlab, matplotlib, plot, axis

I'm trying to plot a soundfield both in matlab and python but if Matlab allows me to do like this:

```
imagesc(x,y,real(sf_vsrc)); colorbar;
axis xy
title('soundfield ground truth');
```

[image]

using python I'm doing like this:

```
plt.imshow(sf_vsrc_gt,extent=[x[0],x[-1],y[0],y[-1]])
plt.colorbar()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Indeed, in Matlb if I don't put "axis xy" I have the same plot as python, so how can I put "axis xy" in python to have the same result as Matlab?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change it via an optional input:

```
plt.imshow(sf_vsrc_gt,extent=[x[0],x[-1],y[0],y[-1]], origin='lower')
```

or by later playing with the `extent` and `origin` properties.